# Trying to replace old random API with the C++11 one

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a piece of existing code that uses random numbers:

```
double Foo(bool b)
{
    double d = 200.0;
    if (b)
    {
        d /= RAND_MAX + 1;
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    }
    return (d / rand());
}
```

I would like to replace it with C++11 equivalent, but have never used that API before.
After going through [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/operator()/) and [this document](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf) I came up with the following code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
class MVCE
{
    private:

    std::default_random_engine m_generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> m_distribution{};

    public:

    MVCE()
    {
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        m_generator.seed(seed);
    }

    double Foo(bool b)
    {
        double d = 200.0;
        if(b)
        {
            d /= m_generator.max() - m_generator.min() + 1;

            unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
            m_generator.seed(seed);
        }
        return (d / (m_generator() - m_generator.min()));
    }
};
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019. When trying out `MVCE` class on Ideone, it works, but Visual studio complains for `m_generator.max()' and`m_generator.min()' with the following error:

```
E0133 expected a member name
```

When hovering over `max()` it shows the `max` macro (`#define max(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))`), while hovering above `min()` shows `min` macro (`#define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))`).

Since I use the new API for the first time, can someone verify that I have used it correctly?
Can someone help me remove the mentioned error?

Comment: are you using Visual Studio and include `<windows.h>`? It is notorious for defining the macros `max` and `min` which wreck havoc in any decent source file. You can avoid this by defining the macro `NOMINMAX`

Comment: Are you sure the old code isn't `static double d = 200.0;` ? `b` appears to be a one-time init flag, but it would change `d` only for one call.

Comment: @MSalters: It was a class variable, but I have tried to keep the code example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complicated. You want [`std::uniform_real_distribution<>(0, 200.0);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: I'm sorry, but personally, I don't think this is a direct answer to the question.

Comment: @JohnDing: He's trying to replace the old `rand()` API with the C++11 API. How is `std::uniform_real_distribution<>` NOT part of the C++11 API ?!

Comment: I think the main problem is *Can someone help me remove the mentioned error?*, I just personally think your answer could be a comment. \ _ \

Comment: @JohnDing: The solution, besides answering the question in the title, also removes the error mentioned in the body text. The upvoted comment by bolov correctly is a comment since it doesn't answer the chief question.